# How to create array of sum of values in lodash

Tags: lodash

My data is

```
[
[{"2018":63},{"2019":28},{"2020":21}],
[{"2018":103},{"2019":200},{"2020":54}],
[{"2017":74},{"2019":76},{"2020":31}]
]
```

and I want array of sum of the values like

```
[112, 357, 181]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Map the array. Flatten each sub-array to an array of values, and sum them:

```js
const arr = [[{"2018":63},{"2019":28},{"2020":21}],[{"2018":103},{"2019":200},{"2020":54}],[{"2017":74},{"2019":76},{"2020":31}]]

const result = _.map(
  arr, 
  s => _.sum(_.flatMap(s, _.values))
)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```